# Entity reference form in views below node

Tags: views, forms, entities

I have a machine content type (clients have machines) and i would like to display all their machines in a view (done) and have a webform/entity form display below the node so that the client can submit issues to the machine. Therefore my end result should look something like this;

Johnny's machines;

**Machine 1 - Model Number 234567**

Form exposed

Sumbit form button

**Machine 2 - Model Number 876543**

Form exposed

Sumbit form

Etc.

Any ideas how I might be able to pull this off?

Thanks

Comment: Is the webform the same for all machines or does each machine have its own form? Does the form have to send an email to the author of the machine node or anything like that? Does the form submission have to have some sort of automated reference to the machine node it was submitted for, or would the person filling out the form add information indicating this reference? Do you have any other information in regards to how the form and machine node interact?

Comment: Hi Rooby thanks for getting back to me, and apologies if my question was unclear. The webform/entityform is the same for each machine but will create a new submission each time. The form has an entity reference to the machine so ideally the reference would grab the field from the node field in the view. Essentially the form submitted must just be submitted against the referenced node?

Comment: [Views Megarow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow)

Comment: Hi J.Reynolds thank you for the response. The Views Megarow module is great but due to it using a filter_xss() function to prevent security issues it strips any possibility of using a prepopulate function on the url. Ity strips the encoding. https://www.drupal.org/node/2131933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After suffering on many different options to get this integrated, I eventually decided to use a workaround. I used the standard node comment form and created a view to display teaser nodes. It works. It's not necessarily the right option but it might help someone looking for something similar.

Thanks for your help guys.